# Vue router - stay in the same url(without redirect)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am using this [simple-router](http://jsfiddle.net/posva/wtpuevc6/) example, but with my own components:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    const Home = { template: '<div id="login"><login-comp></login-comp></div>' };
    const Foo = { template: '<div>Foo</div>' };
    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Home },
        { path: '/foo', component: Foo }
      ]
    })
    new Vue({
        router,
        el: '#router',
        data: {
            msg: 'Hello World'
        }
    })

});
```

It works fine but as a change from one route to another the page redirect to my base `url`, for example my site is:

```
https://example.com/vue/index.jsp
```

after changing to `/foo`, the url changes to

```
https://example.com/foo
```

My index.jsp router:

```
<div id="router">
    <router-link to="/">/home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/foo">/foo</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Thank's for any help.

Comment: If you want to use hashbang URLs instead of actual URLs, then remove the history mode https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html. If you still want to use the history mode, then you should set the `base` option to `/vue` (default is `/`) https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how it's meant to work, when you set mode to history:

```
mode: 'history'
```

Remove that part, and you'll get a hash after your url, and it will work properly.